# How to display the contents of each porject separately?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**How** to display the contents of each porject separately?

**Lists are now displayed for all porjects**

If information is entered in one of the porjects in the admin, it will be displayed for all the porjects.

But I want the information of each porject to be displayed correctly

**views.py:**

```
class ProjectView(ListView):
    template_name = 'project/project.html'
    model = Project
    context_object_name = 'projects'
    ordering = ['-title']
    paginate_by = 2
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        query = super(ProjectView, self).get_queryset()
        data = query.filter(is_active=True)
        return data

class SingleProjectView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'project/single_project.html'
    model = Project
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SingleProjectView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["add_project_option"] = ProjectOption.objects.all()
        return context
```

**html:**

my html(for loop)

```
{% for add_project_option_list in add_project_option %}

<div class="options">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="options__row">
                <h4>{{ add_project_option.name_option }}</h4>
                <p>{{ add_project_option.description_option }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

**models:py**

```
class ProjectOption(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Project', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_option = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    description_option = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

**admin:py**

```
class ProjectOptionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProjectOption
    readonly_fields = ('id',)
    extra = 0
    fields = ['name_option', 'description_option']
```

How do I solve this problem?